# How to enter values in two different text box with same attributes?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide, selenium-grid

[Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bzBM.png)

I used this code

```java
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@type='number'])[1]")).sendKeys("20000");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@required='required'])[2]")).sendKeys("3000");
```

But when it enter value of second textbox the value of first also changes.

Comment: Can you add a snippet of the HTML and also explain the problem a bit more in detail? Currently I don't quite get the situation.

Comment: I have two textboxes in which I have to enter these integer values . But when I run the program first text box enter its value i.e. 20000 but when it comes on second part of that and enters 3000 the values of first text box also becomes 3000

Comment: I would check the xpath, if that is correct. It seems both the xpaths are returning the same textbox. When I deal with so much xpath, I use [BaseX database](http://basex.org/) to verify if the xpaths return what they are supposed to and then use the verified xpaths in my code.

Comment: Its not database I am testing webpage with selenium

Comment: I get that you are testing the webpage with Selenium but the basis for using xpath is that you are operating on some XML. Usually it is the generated HTML of your webpage in your browser. What I mean by verifying it using BaseX is that you get the generated code and load it in BaseX and verify the xpath that you are using. Most likely your xpath is the issue and hence BaseX is a way to make life easy when dealing with xpaths. I personally find it convenient to quickly verify the results there rather than running the program on trial and error basis.